# Is it possible to access parent class's members from a nested class in an aggregation

Tags: python, class, aggregation

My Question is, say i declare a class within a class, as a sort of an aggregation:

```
class A:

    self.foo = 20
    self.bar = 30

    def someFunc(self):

        class B:
            # some code here

        BObject = B()
```

is it possible to access the foo/bar variables from within class B ? If yes, then how ?

I have run into this problem while using wxpython, and needing to write a class within the main frame class to handle a particular custom dialog.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Why are you building B in a method of A?

Comment: Having instance (self) reference in the A class scope doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well its like this, in my program, class A is actually a high level Frame class, and the method of A is an event handler (in the form of def evthandler(self, event): )for the frame. I need to spawn a custom dialog (which is defined as B) whenever the event handler is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    foo = 20
    bar = 30
    def build_b(self):
        class B(object):
            foo = self.foo
            bar = self.bar
        return B()
```

Then you could do:

```
>>> b_obj = A().build_b()

>>> b_obj.foo, b_obj.bar
<<< (20, 30)
```

But, you should really break class `B` out of class `A` if you can, use it's `__init__` method to initialize it...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following correction:

```
>>> class A:
...      foo=20
...      bar=30
...      def build_child(self):
...              class B:
...                      def __init__(self, parent):
...                              self.parent = parent
...              return B(self)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = a.build_child()
>>> b
<__main__.B object at 0x89952ac>
>>> b.parent
<__main__.A object at 0x89956ec>
```

**This way, if you change class A, you don't have to update class B.**